# How do I add file and directory comparision option to mc user menu?

Tags: command-line

I want to add Beyond Compare diff to `mc` (midnight commmander) user menu.

All I know is that I need to add my custom command to `~/.mc/menu` but I have no idea about the syntax to use.

I want to be able to compare two files from the two panes or the directories themselves.

The command that I need to run is `bcompare file1 file2 &` (some for directories, it will figure it out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to `~/.mc/menu`:

```
+ t r & ! t t
d       Diff against file of same name in other directory
        if [ "%d" = "%D" ]; then
          echo "The two directores must be different"
          exit 1
        fi
        if [ -f %D/%f ]; then        # if two of them, then
          bcompare %f %D/%f &
        else
          echo %f: No copy in %D/%f
        fi

x       Diff file to file
        if [ -f %D/%F ]; then        # if two of them, then
          bcompare %f %D/%F &
        else
          echo %f: No copy in %D/%f
        fi

D       Diff current directory against other directory
        if [ "%d" = "%D" ]; then
          echo "The two directores must be different"
          exit 1
        fi
        bcompare %d %D &
```

Comment: The weird `+ t r & ! t t` selectors are explained at http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_mc.php#conditionals . Also, you may want to take advantage of %s (and %D/%S in the other panel): tagged file if there is one, else current file.